# Ctrl+Alt+F1 or stopping causes screen to go blank

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu

I need to install my Nvidia driver. In order to do that I need to stop the X server. Stopping X server:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

makes my screen go blank. Trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> first makes my screen go blank as well. All I can do in both scenarios is a hard reboot.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by uncommenting the `GRUB_TERMINAL` line in GRUB's config file, for example, you could use `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#GRUB_TERMINAL/GRUB_TERMINAL/' /etc/default/grub
```

Or you could do

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

find the line `#GRUB_TERMINAL` and remove the `#`from the start. Save and exit.

Either way, after editing the file, you must run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable lightdm by running

`sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service`

then reboot and install your driver, then

`sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service --now`

when you're done

I might be wrong on the name of the service, or even the whole method